# Update Column C with the difference of Column A & B (Timevalue)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm looking for `UPDATE` query to update 3rd column with the difference of first two column. Below is my data.

```
Table name - Report

Field Name - Data Type
--------------------
New           - Date/Time
Opened        - Date/Time
NewOpen_Time  - Date/Time
```

`NewOpen_Time` is to be updated with the difference of `Opened - NEW`.

Both the columns contains data in below format

`New = 11/18/2015 4:42:46 AM`

`Opened = 11/18/2015 4:51:22 AM`

and I want column `NewOpen_Time` to be updated in below format.

`NewOpen_Time = 0 days, 0 hrs, 8 mins, 36 secs`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL or Access?

Comment: If you have the freedom to choose databases, MariaDB (a MySQL fork) will allow you to to VIRTUAL columns that will automagically maintain inter-field relationships. I do something very similar in a labour-logging table, where the DATETIME out minus the DATETIME in automagically sets the value of the HOURS field.

Comment: I'm using access 2013...so could you help with it? Can we use any udf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatYearDayHourMinuteSecondDiff( _
  ByVal datTimeStart As Date, _
  ByVal datTimeEnd As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparatorDate As String = " ", _
  Optional ByVal strSeparatorTime As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of years, days, hours, minutes and seconds of difference
' between datTimeStart and datTimeEnd converted to
' years, days, hours and minutes and seconds as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of date and/or time separator.
'
' Should return correct output for a negative time span but
' this is not fully tested.
'
' Example:
'   datTimeStart: #2006-05-24 10:03:02#
'   datTimeEnd  : #2009-04-17 20:01:18#
'   returns     : 2 328 09:58:16
'
' 2007-11-06. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Const cintSecondsHour As Integer = 60& * 60&

  Dim intYears      As Integer
  Dim intDays       As Integer
  Dim intSeconds    As Integer
  Dim intHours      As Integer
  Dim datTime       As Date
  Dim strDatePart   As String
  Dim strTimePart   As String
  Dim strYDHMS      As String

  intYears = Years(datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)
  datTimeStart = DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datTimeStart)
  intDays = DateDiff("h", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd) \ 24
  datTimeStart = DateAdd("d", intDays, datTimeStart)
  intHours = DateDiff("h", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)
  datTimeStart = DateAdd("h", intHours, datTimeStart)
  intSeconds = DateDiff("s", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)

  ' Format year and day part.
  strDatePart = CStr(intYears) & strSeparatorDate & CStr(intDays)
  datTime = TimeSerial(intHours, 0, intSeconds Mod cintSecondsHour)
  ' Format hour, minute and second part.
  strTimePart = Format(datTime, "hh\" & strSeparatorTime & "nn\" & strSeparatorTime & "ss")
  strYDHMS = strDatePart & " " & IIf(datTime < 0, "-", "") & strTimePart

  FormatYearDayHourMinuteSecondDiff = strYDHMS

End Function
```

Just modify `strDatePart` and `strTimePart` to fit your need.

Then in your query:

```
NewOpen_Time: FormatYearDayHourMinuteSecondDiff([New],[Opened])
```

**Edit**

The calculation of years you can just remove, as I guess it will not be relevant here, or you can use this function:

```
' Returns the difference in full years between Date1 and Date2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   any date/time value of data type Date
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of year counts.
' For a given Date1, if Date2 is decreased stepwise one year from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If LinearSequence is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If LinearSequence is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If LinearSequence is False, reversing Date1 and Date2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If LinearSequence is True, reversing Date1 and Date2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28th when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29th
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2015-11-24. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Years( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal LinearSequence As Boolean) _
    As Long

    Dim YearCount   As Long
    Dim DayCount    As Long

    DayCount = DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2)

    If DayCount = 0 Then
        ' The dates are equal.
    Else
        ' Find difference in calendar years.
        YearCount = DateDiff("yyyy", Date1, Date2)
        ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
        ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a 1 year period
        ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
        If DayCount > 0 Then
            If DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", YearCount, Date1), Date2) < 0 Then
                YearCount = YearCount - 1
            End If
        Else
            If DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", -YearCount, Date2), Date1) < 0 Then
                YearCount = YearCount + 1
            End If
            ' Offset negative count of years to continuous sequence if requested.
            If LinearSequence = True Then
                YearCount = YearCount - 1
            End If
        End If
    End If

    ' Return count of years as count of full year periods.
    Years = YearCount

End Function
```

Comment: And how will I use this function in my query.?

Comment: They will also need the code for your `Years()` function.

Comment: @HansUp: Oops, thanks. I've added it, though probably not of much use in this context.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks!!! `FormatYearDayHourMinuteSecondDiff`is working. tk you for the help.